# Debugging some pattern printing code in C

Tags: arrays, c

I'm writing code for a problem involving printing patterns of "*".

I'm trying to print out a block of N by N square (where N is a power of 3 such as 3, 9, 27...) using "*" and clear out the middle bit like so:

N=3

```
***
* *
***
```

N=9

```
*********
*********
*********
***   ***
***   ***
***   ***
*********
*********
*********
```

N=27

```
***************************
***************************
***************************
***************************
***************************
***************************
***************************
***************************
***************************
*********         *********
*********         *********
*********         *********
*********         *********
*********         *********
*********         *********
*********         *********
*********         *********
*********         *********
***************************
***************************
***************************
***************************
***************************
***************************
***************************
***************************
***************************
```

In my code, I make a N by N 2D array of "*" first, and then use the function eraseMiddle() to "carve out" the middle bit.

Here is my code:

```
int eraseMiddle(int n, char array[n][n]) {
    for(int i=n/3; i<2*n/3; i++) {
        for (int j=n/3; j<2*n/3; j++) {
            strcpy(&array[i][j], " ");
            //printf("empty ");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


int main() {
    int N;
    scanf("%d", &N);
    
    //creating sqaure of size NxN
    char starsArray[N][N];
    for (int i=0;i<N;i++) {
        for (int j=0;j<N;j++) {
            strcpy(&starsArray[i][j], "*");
        }
    }
    
    eraseMiddle(N, starsArray);
    
    //test
    for (int i=0;i<N;i++) {
        for (int j=0;j<N;j++) {
            printf("%c", starsArray[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    

    
    return 0;
}
```

Without the erasing part, the code prints out a block of solid N by N "*" just fine. However, when the erasing function is used, it prints it out as so:

```
9
*********
*********
*********
***   **
***   **
***   **
*********
*********
*********
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

The absence of the last star in the line occurs for greater inputs as well.

I can't seem to understand what's wrong with the code I've written.

If anyone could help, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Your question is good by StackOverflow standards, with own effort demonstrated and appropriate code shown. It deserves the good answer on your immediate problem below, by MikeCAT. On the long term however, let me recommend to keep things simpler. In this case using an array, filling it and then changing the content is too complex. For things like this you are supposed to come up wih a loop construct which simply prints the desired pattern directly. I.e. print a lot of `"*"` then a pattern of `"*"`s, `" "`s and more `"*"`s. Then `"*"`a again. And please take the [tour], for good luck. Have fun.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I'll take note.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strcpy` is for copying strings, so you shouldn't use that for manipluating one character. It writes terminating null-character and results in destroying adjacent characters.

```
strcpy(&array[i][j], " ");
```

and

```
strcpy(&starsArray[i][j], "*");
```

should be

```
array[i][j] = ' ';
```

and

```
starsArray[i][j] = '*';
```

(use single quotation marks instead of double to represent characters)

Comment: I really like how you helpfully explain OPs immediate problem and how to solve, instead of any kind of "here is how you do it efficiently" code. Do not change this. ;-) I have however added a comment on the long term perspective. Also not really giving code.